# cocoa mousedown on a window and mouse up in another

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouseevent, first-responder

I am developping a Cocoa application and I have a special need. In my main window, when I mouse down on a certain area, a new window (like a complex tooltip) appears. I want to be able to do:
- mouse down on the main window (mouse button stay pressed)
- user moves the mouse on the "tooltip" window and mouseup on it.

My issue is that the tooltip window does nto get any mousevent until the mouseup.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And it won't since mouse is tracked by the main window. However, you can process **mouseUp** in the main window, transform click coordinates into the desktop space, get tooltip window frame and check whether the click occurred on the tooltip. After that, you can send a message to the tooltip window manually.

Or you can try to find another way to implement the final goal :) It is usually better to follow the rules, in this case - mouse tracking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, event "forwarding" seems to be a good option. How do you send a mouse event from one window to another one?

Comment: NSWindow has a -sendEvent: method.